# How to fix black screen on Google Chrome mobile load page

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Whit the Google Chrome last release (72.0.3626.105) and Canary when i load some page of my web app (vb.net, jquery) the screen of my device become black.
If i resize or lock/unlock my device the browser show me correctly the form.

If i connect my device to "Remote debugging" on google chrome and "inspect" i can't see the page and there aren't error in console.

When the page is black the html is "alive" an if i tap over a button (not visible) it works.

[This is the state of device.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDz3m.jpg)

Comment: This is happening on our sites as well all of a sudden. Following.

Comment: This happening with the newer versions of Google Chrome. The same web app or sites on firefox mobile work correctly.

Comment: was there any workaround for this bug?

Comment: Any update of this issue? The problem still persists. Thank you.

Comment: The bug got fixed Feb 28:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=933374 But it doesn't seem to have made it in the next version of Chrome Android:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/72.0.3626.105..72.0.3626.121?pretty=fuller&n=10000 But the next version again should release with the bug fix (mid April?).

Comment: cant wait until they fix this, this is really damaging - if anyone has an idea for a fix it would be highly appriciated

Comment: uninstall any updates to the browser on android devices removes the bug from my end so i can use it again and then disabling automatic update of it until theres a fix for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chrome Beta 73 was updated yesterday (73.0.3683.67).
Here the bug-fix was included:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/73.0.3683.58..73.0.3683.67?pretty=fuller&n=10000

Chrome 73 is estimated to be stable in 5 days from now (Mar 12):
https://www.chromestatus.com/features/schedule

So we should have a solution for our users very soon :-)

Answer (score 0):

My Solution, works like a charm:

1. Go to Settings
2. Apps
3. Look for **Chrome Dev** App
4. Go to Storage
5. Clear cache and other data.
6. Force stop
7. Restart the app.

That's it!! 
Thank me later.