# chrome on android : my webpages sometimes appears to be full black - need to ex rotate to get it shown?

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-chrome

got this really odd and frustrating issue on my android tablet/android phone, got a  webapp (html5/javascript/css) that works fine on chrome desktop - but on mobile and tablet chrome, it happens all too often that when i click into a new page, then the output in the browser is just a pure black page.

What i then can do is to either rotate the device so the screen switches orientation and then the page appears like magic, or i can ex press the multi-tab button and then just click back and it shows.

So it somehow seems to be about redrawing not reloading the page.

Its not everytime it happens but it happens quite alot and i get nothing in debugging or any hints to what is going on.

Looked through the internet for similar issues and there are a few but they are either not replied or they are focused around some youtube issues back some time, or very old issues (2011/2012) - nothing that really points into the problem here.

Anyone have any idea here or input to how i can fix this without having the user to rotate the screen all the time ? its really affecting the usage.

note 1: it is quite heavy on some places on javascript so its not just a standard webpage

note :running latest android latest chrome on android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look here. It's the same bug.:
[How to fix black screen on Google Chrome mobile load page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54744140/how-to-fix-black-screen-on-google-chrome-mobile-load-page)

The bug got fixed Feb 28: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=933374

But it doesn't seem to have made it in the next version of Chrome Android: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/72.0.3626.105..72.0.3626.121?pretty=fuller&n=10000

But the next version again should release with the bug fix (mid April?).

Meanwhile, did you find an easy js workaround for this issue? 
Our site is currently useless until this bug-fix get released for Chrome Android?

Comment: thanks for your feedback as we are going crazy here as its also totally unusable in chrome on android. Have no idea how we can fix it on JS - do you know if Firefox could be an option ?

Comment: sounds like on your link that firefox might be the option to avoid it ?

Comment: Chrome Beta 73 was updated yesterday (73.0.3683.67). Here the bug-fix was included: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+log/73.0.3683.58..73.0.3683.67?pretty=fuller&n=10000

Chrome 73 is estimated to be stable in 5 days from now (Mar 12): https://www.chromestatus.com/features/schedule

So we should have a solution for our users very soon :-)

Comment: that is awesome cant wait this one been brutal